# No "GPU emulation" option in Android emulator settings

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to enable GPU acceleration in Android emulator, but there's no `GPU emulation` option in the AVD settings.

[image]

My config: Win8 @ AMD Phenom II + Eclipse Juno + up-to-date Android SDK 20.0.3

Am I missing something? Is the GPU acceleration not supported on AMD platform or Win8? Here is a screenshot from [korri's blog](http://www.korri.net/blog/2012/4/12-how-to-enable-gpu-acceleration-in-android-emulator.html):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While creating AVD.. In your hardware Goto New and select the features you want... Refer to this picture[image]

Comment: How could I have missed that! :-) On the other side, it is still laggy, no luck on my macbook either...

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 4.21  GPU can be enabled in given option as in the screenshot

- Goto AVD manager
- Click Create/Edit Option

Their you can see the option to Enable GPU

[image][![
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZsMR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZsMR.png)